# Laravel Uploading Image via API

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload an image via API and it keep throwing this error on my log and images are not uploading.

> [2020-03-06 16:27:46] local.ERROR: Reading Exif data is not supported by this PHP installation. {"userId":10002,"exception":"[object] (Intervention\Image\Exception\NotSupportedException(code: 0): Reading Exif data is not supported by this PHP installation. at /home/zackdemo/public_html/app/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Commands/ExifCommand.php:22)
>       [stacktrace]

Comment: Provide your api controller and please specify what you're using as your front end

Comment: Your PHP installation doesn't have EXIF support. Intervention Image requires EXIF support.

Answer (score -1):

You can encode the image in a base64 format before sending it to the server. PHP have tools to decode the base 64 format.

You can do something like the following.

```
public static function storeBase64($base64Image, $extension, $participant)
{
    $oldImage = $participant->image;

    $image = $base64Image; // your base64 encoded
    $image = str_replace('data:image/' . $extension . ';base64,', '', $image);
    $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
    $imageName = str_random(10) . "-" . $participant->id . '.' . $extension;
    $path = 'storage/participant/profile/' . $imageName;
    Storage::put($path, base64_decode($image));
    $participant->image = $path;
    $participant->save();

    if ($oldImage) {
        // Storage::delete($oldImage);
        Storage::move($oldImage, 'deleted/' . $oldImage  );
    }

    return $path;

}
```

Comment: Try to provide better example, as people are prone to copy and paste code onto their editor, desperately looking for solution, not giving a damn what they actually paste and spread further if it 'finally' works for them. The answer is very sloppy and bad shpaghetti example, and could be explained much better in a pure procedural manner. str_replace, for instance, can also work with arrays, no need to repeat it twice. PHP manual has that explained very nicely.